# Is there a way to make EF database first migration follow C# naming conventions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm developing a web application using ASP.Net MVC 5, and Entity Framework 6. I've performed a database first migration based off of the below database schema.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database`.`table_name` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `some_value` INT NULL,
    `some_other_value` INT NULL,
    `some_other_ohter_value` INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

This results in the following class being generated:

```
public partial class table_name
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int some_value { get; set; }
    public int some_other_value { get; set; }
    public int some_other_ohter_value { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the class name, and properties directly match that of the table schema. **Is there a way to have this class follow Pascal Case per C# naming conventions as per below?**

```
public partial class TableName
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherOtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How did you do the database first migration?

If you generate a database from your schema and run this command (in the visual studio package manager console), I've found that the code generated follows C# standard naming conventions.

```
$tables = @('table_name')
Scaffold-DbContext $connstring Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir 'DataAccess/Models' -Tables $tables -Force
```

You'll need the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` nuget package to access the `Scaffold-DbContext` cmdlet.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

Comment: It seems the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools nuget package does not support .net framework 4.5 - any ideas?

Comment: I've followed [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx) to perform the migration.

Comment: Is this project greenfield? And if so is .net 4.6.x out of the question?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: If you didn't mind a little hackery, you could create a new library (outside of the context of your current sln) with matching namespaces that targets 4.6.x, generate your context, and move the files over